# Commonsware Cwac camera dependency issue

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Issue with building My android app can't find dependency, not sure what the issue is. It was working yesterday and haven't changed any code.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.6.+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/commonsware/cwac/camera-v9/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/commonsware/cwac/camera-v9/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera-v9/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera-v9/
         https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera-v9/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com/com/commonsware/cwac/camera-v9/
```

Any one know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This would have been better to file as an issue in the project issue tracker.

That being said, I screwed up the CommonsWare artifact repo. I am repairing it now, as part of moving the projects to Android 1.0 and a new means of publishing the AARs to the artifact repo. This project should be working again in a few hours. At that point, you may need to use **`gradle --refresh-dependencies`** to get Gradle to pick up the missing dependency, as it only checks for dependencies once every 24 hours.

My apologies for my screwup.